# Animated button not visible in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation, uibutton

My application has a list of servers in an UITableView, which among other things show if you are connected to the server with an image. This is currently working fine with static images.

I now want to add a very rudimentary animation that shows that it's in the process of connecting to a server. Just blinking between "connected" and "disconnected" images.

But when I set the image of the button to an animation it displays nothing at all, not any frame of the animation, not the default image of the tablecell, just blank. Creating an animation like this works on buttons in the view that are not in the table so creating the animation is not the issue. It does start playing when the button is pressed, making me think the button just needs a refresh or forced redraw. But I haven't been able to find anything.

I reload my table using reloadData.

(Simplified) Source of ServerCell.h:

```
@interface ServerCell : UITableViewCell 

    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *ipLabel;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *serverImageView;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *mConnectionBtn;

@end
```

ServerCell.m

```
@implementation ServerCell

#pragma mark - Properties

@synthesize nameLabel;
@synthesize ipLabel;
@synthesize serverImageView;
@synthesize mConnectionBtn;

#pragma mark - Constructor/Destructor 

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*
 * Class constructor
 */
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Class Methods

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*
 * Communicate to the superview the user selection
 */
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

@end
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Cast the TableCell to a custom ServerCell
    ServerCell *cell = (ServerCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ServerCell"];

    [cell.mConnectionBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(ActionServerCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    NSArray* images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"connected.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"disconnected.png"], nil];
    UIImage* anim = [UIImage animatedImageWithImages:images duration:1.0];

    [cell.mConnectionBtn setImage:anim forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // return the cell object
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want. You might have to tweak when you call the start animation.

```
import UIKit

class ExampleTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var names = ["John", "Will", "Ana"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "cell"
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
            cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "red")!
            cell?.imageView?.animationImages = [UIImage(named: "red")!, UIImage(named: "green")!]
            cell?.imageView?.animationDuration = 3
            cell?.imageView?.animationRepeatCount = 0
            cell?.imageView?.startAnimating()
        }
        cell!.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to modify it a bit to work with what I have. But the concept of only creating the animation once and then running startanimation or stopanimation depending on what I need solved it. Apparently setting the image to the same animation again was breaking something originally, still not sure why, but it works now and that's good enough for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem =) From my tests I had to set "imageView?.image" and "imageView?.animationImages". Just setting "imageView?.animationImages" wasn't working. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

To show the process is being working you could simply add an `activityIndicator` instead of your image.

It might be simpler than set your animated image.

1. Connect it to you xib :

`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;`

2. If you do not need it just set in you cell.m :

`cell.activityIndicator.hidden = YES;`

3. And then when your process is working turn it on :

`self.activityIndicator.hidden = NO;`

If I'm wrong or if I missunderstood the question, please let me know :)